# Show data from another table when logged on ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, membership-provider

I'm using ASP .NET with Oracle XE as my database and I use the ASP .NET Membership tools with Oracle as my provider. The ASP .NET Membership tool creates its own set of tables on my database.
My question is how can I show the data from the MemberInformation table when the user is logged on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Membership` and `MembershipUser' in the`System.Web.Security`

```
  MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
  string userEmail=  user.Email;
```

Now using the `user` object you can access most information of the currently logged in user. These classes are powerful you can even use them to update user data.

See these Links for details:
[MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx)
[Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx)